# Splitting a string at a specified character and storing them in a vector

Tags: c++, string, vector, split

I'm working on my own string class and I'm having trouble with this "split" function. The idea is to pass a character, the function looks for the character, splits the string at every instance of it, then stores the resulting strings into a vector. For example. split('r') for the word tree would return a vector containing "t" and "ee". Here's my function:

```
std::vector<String> String::split(char c) const{
    std::vector<String> result;
    int start = 0, end;
    int i = 0;

    while(ptr[i] != 0) {
        if(ptr[i] == c) {
            end = i;
            result.push_back(substr(start, end - 1));
            start = end + 1;
        }
        ++i;
    }

    result.push_back(substr(start, length() - 1));

    return result;
}
```

Every time I run this, it gives me a bad_alloc error. Any ideas?

Edit 1: My substr() takes starting and ending position, unlike the std::string substr()

Comment: What does your `substr()` function look like? `std::string::substr()` takes position and length as parameters but you are passing start and end position.

Comment: For one thing, if the first character in the string is equal to `c` then you call `substr(0, -1)`. I doubt that will go well, and without seeing your code my guess is that it will attempt to allocate 2GB.

Comment: Does your `String` class have proper copy behavior? I.e. did you implement the "Rule of Three" or alternatively use a smart pointer / container like vector?

Comment: It's troubling that you use a terminal `0` *and* a `length()` method, but I see nothing else wrong. Until you give us a [minimal complete example](http://sscce.org) I don't think we can help you.

Comment: Depending on how your `substr` works ((begin, length) or (begin, end)?) I'm almost sure that @SteveJessop had the right idea. This means you should write `end` instead of `end-1` as well as `length()` instead of `length()-1`. And `length()` can be replaced with `i`, since `i` "points" at the terminating zero at the end.

Comment: This is not enough information to diagnose your problem.  The issue is elsewhere, perhaps your copy constructor, perhaps your destructor, or your `substr` function, or a combination of the above.

Comment: You can use boost::split().